# SASS - Include font-face in file

Tags: css, sass

I have a web page that references a CSS file. This CSS file is generated from a SASS file. This SASS file has been working fine for me for a while. Now, I need to import glyphicons from a custom directory. In a CSS file used elsewhere in my app, I have the following:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('/pub/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('/pub/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
       url('/pub/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), 
       url('/pub/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), 
       url('/pub/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), 
       url('/pub/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
  }
```

This works in a CSS file. But, when I add it to my .scss file, it doesn't seem to work. While I don't see any errors, I can't use "Glyphicons Halflings" for the `font-family` value in my other CSS classes.

I'm trying to use the following:

```
.checkmark {
    color: #fff;
    content: "\f00c";
    font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings";
}
```

The only thing I see on the screen is a white box though.

How do I use the `font-family` mixin in a SASS file?

Comment: "It doesn't seem to work". Have you checked if the font-face is in the output CSS, and if it is indeed correct? It helps to know if this issue is caused by an incorrect conversion from SCSS to CSS, or maybe by other styles in the final CSS that interfere with this one.

Comment: @GolezTrol Yeah... I checked the output CSS. It looks correct. That's what's odd about this.